tFTPConnection in talend open studio for data integration
i made an FTP connection to a remote ftp server it is working great but i have a problem with the password, on that machine the password changes every 2 weeks, is there a way to make an ftp connection that asks for input password every time im running it insted of giving it a static password and changing it once every 2 weeks?
thanks in advance!!
i tried using contexts to ask for a password before running but i cant figure out how to make the password to relate to the context

it's possible in your studio you have to create a context variable with the prompt option checked like this :

Then you have to configure your FTP component (for example I used the tFTPConnection) and in the "Password" field you have to put your context variable like this :

And when you execute your job it will prompt a window like this where you can set your new password.

But you will have to set it every time you execute your job and it only works within the studio so if you build your job and execute using the scripts it doesn't work.
Hope this helps
